# Minion throwing exception with list

Tags: sitecore-commerce, minion

I'm getting a strange behavior with `Sitecore 8.2 and commerce 8.2.1`.
Every time a custom minion runs it throws the following exception:

```
ERROR SQL:block:findentitiesinlist.Error: Message=Attempted to divide by zero.|Trace=   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL.FindEntitiesInListBlock.d__4.MoveNext()
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL.FindEntitiesInListBlock.d__4.MoveNext()
```

I decompiled the `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL plugin` and noticed that it fails in the FindEntitiesInListBlock when the 'Take' property in the argument is 0:
[image]

The reason why it fails is because when it is setting the PageCount property it tries to devide the count with the Take argument and if it is 0 it explains the DivideByZero exception.

```
CommerceList<CommerceEntity> commerceList = new CommerceList<CommerceEntity>()
        {
          Name = arg.ListName,
          DisplayName = arg.ListName,
          CurrentPage = 1,
          TotalItemCount = num,
          PageCount = (int) Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((int) num / arg.Take)),
          SearchOptions = new SearchOption()
          {
            Skip = arg.Skip,
            Take = arg.Take,
            ListMemberships = new List<string>()
            {
              arg.ListName
            }
          }
        };
```

What should be changed in the minion definition to prevent this error from happening? I don't see where the 'Take' argument is set. And just to be clear my code is not calling the FindEntitiesInList pipeline directly. I suspect that this is being called under the hood by Sitecore's own plugin

**Here is my minion definition:**

```
{
        "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.MinionPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
        "WakeupInterval": "00:15:00",
        "ListToWatch": "NoFulfillmentList",
        "FullyQualifiedName": "MyType, MyAssembly",
        "ItemsPerBatch": 10,
        "SleepBetweenBatches": 500,
        "PolicyId": "7bb82d2a3adc9fd2cebf69b11f472d84",
        "Models": {
          "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Model, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
          "$values": [

          ]
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument that sets it to 0 is in the pipeline argument invoke:

```
long listCount = await this.GetListCount(this.Policy.ListToWatch);
FulfillmentMinionArgument orderMinionArgument = new FulfillmentMinionArgument((await this.GetListIds<Order>(this.Policy.ListToWatch, Convert.ToInt32(listCount))).IdList, this.Policy.ListToWatch);
```

The way to fix that is to add an 'if' checking if listCount > 0 before calling the Run method to make sure it only runs when the list is not empty

```
if (listCount > 0)
      await minionPipeline.Run(ordersMinionArgument, executionContextOptions);
```